# HtmlAnchor.ServerClick eventhandler doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created my `HtmlAnchor` dynamically like this (I have to create these links dynamically, because they are in text.):

```
Panel myDiv = new Panel();

myDiv.ID = "moreInfoLink";
HtmlAnchor anchor = new HtmlAnchor();
anchor.ServerClick += new EventHandler(loadMoreInfoHandler);
anchor.ID = "news" + index.ToString();
anchor.InnerText = "More information ...";
anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "linkStyle");

myDiv.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

And my handler looks like this:

```
void loadMoreInfoHandler(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    //load something here.
}
```

But this `loadMoreInfoHandler` was not fired (I have a break point there, and it was not stopped by).

What should i do now?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you recreate this anchor in the pageload event on postback?

Comment: You could use a LinkButton insted of an html Anchor, and set the click event

Comment: I tried a LinkButton but got the same behavior as when using an HTMLAnchor, why doesn't the event trigger?

Answer (score -1):

You are not wiring the event properly... the control that you've added i.e. ha...is not the one that's trying to call the serverclick event... here's what you need to do...

and also you need to `HRef = "#"`

```
AddHandler ha.ServerClick, AddressOf LinkClick    '>>>LinkClick is the click method

ha.ID = "D1"
ha.Attributes.Add("onServerClick", "LinkClick")
ha.HRef = "#"
ha.InnerText = "Click Here"
Page.Controls.Add(ha)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out at the weekend. But what should i write in LinkClick, should I write it like a normal Handler with Object and EventArgs?